# Как передать параметр enum[]?

Tags: c#

Хочу реализовать программу для получения баланса и последних платежей с QIWI. Использую библиотеку QiwiApi, но столкнулся с проблемой что не совсем понимаю как правильно передать параметр Source[].

Метод который нужен:

```
    public static async Task<PaymentHistoryResponse> PaymentHistoryAsync(string walletId, int rows, Operation operation, Source[] sources, DateTime? startDate = null, DateTime? endDate = null, DateTime? nextTxnDate = null, long? nextTxnId = null)
        {
            if (!Initialized) throw new NotInitializedException();
            if (!ValidatePhoneNumber(walletId)) throw new ArgumentException("Invalid wallet id.");
            var query = new Dictionary<string, object>
            {
                {"rows", rows },
                {"operation", operation.ToString() }
            };

            for (int i = 0; i < sources.Length; i++)
                query.Add("source[" + i + "]", sources[i].ToString());

            if (startDate != null && endDate != null)
            {
                query.Add("startDate", startDate.Value.ToString("s") + "Z");
                query.Add("endDate", endDate.Value.ToString("s") + "Z");
            }

            if(nextTxnDate != null && nextTxnId != null)
            {
                query.Add("nextTxnDate", nextTxnDate.Value.ToString("s") + "Z");
                query.Add("nextTxnId", nextTxnId);
            }

            var response =  await ApiCallAsync("payment-history/v1/persons/" + walletId + "/payments", query);
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<PaymentHistoryResponse>(await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());
                return data;
            }
            switch ((int)response.StatusCode)
            {
                case 401: throw new UnauthorizedException();
                case 404: throw new TransactionNotFoundException();
            }

            response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
            return null;
        }
```

Класс Source: 
    `public enum Source
        {
            /// <summary>
            /// Russian Ruble Qiwi Wallet.
            /// </summary>
            QW_RUB,
            /// <summary>
            /// United States Dollar Qiwi Wallet.
            /// </summary>
            QW_USD,
            /// <summary>
            /// Euro Qiwi Wallet.
            /// </summary>
            QW_EUR,
            /// <summary>
            /// Binded card.
            /// </summary>
            CARD,
            /// <summary>
            /// Mobile phone balance.
            /// </summary>
            MK
        }`

Comment: @AlexF спасибо большое

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Например можно сделать как то так:

```
enum Number
{
    One,
    Two,
    Three,
    Four,
    Five
}

static List<int> GetNumber(Number[] numbers)
{
    var list = new List<int>();
    foreach (var number in numbers)
    {
        if (number == Number.One) list.Add(1);
        else if (number == Number.Two) list.Add(2);
        else if (number == Number.Three) list.Add(3);
        else if (number == Number.Four) list.Add(4);
        else if (number == Number.Five) list.Add(5);
    }
    return list;
}

var numbers = GetNumber( new Number[] { Number.Two, Number.Four } );

numbers.ForEach(b =>
{
    Console.WriteLine($"N{b}: {b}");
});
```